# Making a div position:fixed only after it is scrolled to

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div that is 100% of the viewport height as a landing image for the page, after the user scrolls there is a navigation div, once the div is scrolled to I want it's position to be fixed to the top of the page from that point in.

```
<div class="landing-panel" id="introduction">
    <h1>Site Title</h1>
</div>

    <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>NavItem1</li>
            <li>Navitem2</li>
        </ul>   
    </div>


div.landing-panel{/* Unique landing panel */    
    height:100vh;
    background-image: url('../img/landing-panel-background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; 
}

div.navigation{
    height:10vh;
    background-color: orange;
    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
    top:100vh;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: You mean like `position: sticky;`?

Comment: position: sticky; isn't supported by Google Chrome

Comment: Yes, but there are JS libraries that support this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to use jQuery for that. You have firstly to detect that there is a scroll, and then append the right class to the div you want to stay fixed.

**EDIT**

Added a `var sticky = "sticky"` which defines explicitly the name of the class.

```
var hdr = 150;
var sticky = "sticky";
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if( $(window).scrollTop() > hdr ) {
    $(".your-div").addClass(sticky);
  } else {
    $(".your-div").removeClass(sticky);
  }
});
```

Where `.sticky` is a class with whatever CSS properties you want.

Comment: (apologies, i'm terrible at jQuery) so ".your-div" will be ".navigation" and (sticky) will be .sticky{position: fixed;} in the CSS?

Comment: Yes. But look at the updated code, 'cause I've done a small mistake, which I will fix it right away. See also this: https://jsfiddle.net/1yz8jvoz/